# Give a bash script suid permissions

Tags: linux, bash, startup

I have been doing a lot of research but haven't found anything that really answers my question.

I wrote a bash script that automatically changes the nice values on certain processes. This script needs to run on startup (I currently have it in startup application) and needs `suid` permissions to actually change the nice values. I've tried a few things with chmod and changing ownership of the file over to root but nothing seems to be working. I keep getting a "permission denied" when the script runs.

It runs fine when i manually start it in terminal using: `sudo ./myfile`
but does not work when started on bootup

I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first copy your script in `/etc/init.d`
then(for redhat based servers like centos)

```
chmod +x script.sh
chkconfig --add script.sh
chkconfig --level 0123456 script.sh on
```

For Debian based like ubuntu:
[help](http://tjworld.net/wiki/Linux/Ubuntu/RunlevelAtBoot)
[help2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228402/boot-to-runlevel-3)
[help3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335242/how-to-install-an-init-d-script-in-ubuntu)

try:

```
cp /path/to/your/script.sh /etc/init.d/ 
chmod +x /etc/init.d/yourscript.sh
update-rc.d yourscript defaults
```

Runlevels are logical groups of tasks. Traditionally you have five run levels.

```
0 boot
1 single user 
2 not used
3 multiuser
4 not used 
5 gui
6 reboot
```

Comment: I just edited it to my original post,  but i am running ubuntu.

Comment: I answered and completed it

Answer (score 1):

if you are in debian/ubuntu, do the following:

```
cp /path/to/your/script.sh /etc/init.d/ 

chmod +x /etc/init.d/yourscript.sh

update-rc.d yourscript defaults
```

here i think you should get a warning that LSB TAGS are missing, LSB TAGS are instructions for boot order ...
but if your script is a basic script, ignore the warning and reboot your computer.